# cache_archive param only downloads some jars for the <object> applet

Tags: java, applet

I'm using this code to define an applet with jar cache versioning:

```
<object classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0014-0002-0000-ABCDEFFEDCBA">
<param name="width" value="500" />
<param name="height" value="200" />
<param name="codebase" value="client/" />
<param name="name" value="FooApplet" />
<param name="codetype" value="application/x-java-applet" />
<param name="cache_option" value="plugin" />
<param name="cache_archive" value="a.jar, b.jar, c.jar, d.jar" />
<param name="cache_version" value="1.0.0.0, 1.0.0.0, 1.0.0.0, 1.0.0.0" />
<param name="code" value="com.teo.MyClass.class" />
<param name="initial_focus" value="false"/>
</object>
```

My code is a lot bigger, i have more jars than this but only 3 get downloaded. And I don't understand what makes these 3 jars special because you can find all the jars in the codebase folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: it seems the jars are downloaded, to a separate cache, because I enabled some tracing in the Java console. But my .class file is not found by the applet in one of the jars although the jar is downloaded.

UPDATE 2: i figured this out: if you have a version.xml file your cache_version values should correspond to the versions in the version.xml. This is essentially the same as the versioned Java Web Start protocol for JNLP.

Comment: Caching of the JAR files specified in the manifest's CLASSPATH variable using Java Plug-in's cache is currently not supported. From [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet-caching.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet-caching.html). Check your manifest file in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can you explain exactly what this means?

Comment: i don't see any CLASSPATH variable in the MANIFEST.MF...

Comment: also, if you mean the general META-INF folder (so not inside the jar), i see only this:Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Created-By: 14.2-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: ZipSelfExtractor

Comment: This means it wasn't you case - because you didn't configure manifest. So my suggestion won't help you.

Comment: check out this one [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3214098/801466](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3214098/801466)

Comment: `"plugin"` in that linked doc. has a capital letter `"Plugin"`.  What is `cache_version`?